# There are a lot of gifts missing

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking, number-sequence, formation-of-numbers

> 1-108-121-128-146-157-195-227-305-315-???
> There are a lot of gifts missing

There is a missing 11th number which is it?

This is not on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) :)

Comment: Is the awkward grammar & capitalization intended?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are all

> the days of the year of French public holidays in 2022.

The missing number is

> 359 (Christmas Day).

Comment: Indeed, this matches with the "lot of gifts"...